# jQuery wildcard in selector

Tags: jquery

in my DOM I have a Table which dynamically generates dialogs. The dialog in the DOM will have this form of ID:

- `id="page:form:0:dlg"`
- `id="page:form:1:dlg"`
- `id="page:form:2:dlg"`

Now I want to select the dialog using jquery:

`$("#page\\:form\\:0\\:dlg")`

This of course only works for the first one. Can I somehow specify a Wildcard in the selector?
`$("#page\\:form\\:*\\:dlg")`

Thanks

Comment: Is the issue solved, or still open?

Comment: FYI, if you have any control of these generated dialogs, then add a common class name `class="dlg"` and then you can just use `$('.dlg')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since everything follows the same pattern, you can use `^` selector:

```
$('[id^="page\:form"]')
```

Also, don't use double `\\`. Strangely, it works with or without the `\`.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $('[id^="page\:form"]').css({
    "background": "red",
    "color": "white"
  });
});
```

```css
div {padding: 15px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page:form:0:dlg">Should turn red</div>
<div id="something:0">Should not turn red</div>
<div id="page:form:1:dlg">Should turn red</div>
<div id="something:1">Should not turn red</div>
<div id="page:form:2:dlg">Should turn red</div>
```